# How to efficiently check whether given URL(String) contains whitelist domain(String) in Java

Tags: java, string, url, apache-stringutils

I need to write a utility method which will take a url and check whether given url is valid or not ?

URL can be anything with/without protocol like http, https or with can contain the relative url like if domain is `example` and url is "abc.com" then its a relative URL. also **it can be invalid url as well and can contain simple string**.

Also i've list of whitelisted URL and can change runtime like `youtube.com`, `facebook.com` etc.

How can i check if given url is valid in my case, some basic check which i am doing is below :-

```
 String url = "http://youtube.com";
    if(!StringUtil.isEmpty(url))
    {
        if (url.startsWith("http:") || pathToImage.startsWith("https://")) {
            // check if url is from whitlist domains

        } else {
            // do nothing, url is not internal domain.
        }
    }
```

Now my question is how do i properly extract the domain name from the URL which will be after the `http` or `https`.

Note:- I am using apache StringUtils and its quite possible that url can be like `https://absdsbsb` or `https://anmds.txt`. Also let me know if its a good case for regex matching ?

Comment: _Don't_ reinvent the wheel, use Java's [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class.  It has getter methods for the various component of a URL, and allows to tell whether that component even exists.  It should be relatively easy to run your blacklists and whitelists against the information which can be gotten from the `URL` class.

Comment: in my method i am getting this as a String, so will have to convert it to URI or URL , i can't change the logic to get it into URI or URL , let me know if this conversion of from string to URI is fine ?

Comment: AFAIK you can create a Java `URL` from a string representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use the [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class.

You can treat them as strings and look for particular patterns or substrings, but there are various "tricky" ways to write URLs that could be used to pass through URLs that shouldn't.  (Though, if you are using a whitelist rather than a blacklist, that makes it more difficult to be tricky.)

Anyhow, the approach should be to use the `URI` class to parse the URL string, then get and match the `protocol` and `host` components.

Once you have the domain name, it is a bit of a toss-up how you *efficiently* match it against a white-list, but I would look at using a TreeSet, and consider using its `floor` and `ceiling` methods to accelerate domain prefix matching.

(I would be surprised if regex matching would give you good performance.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , now i am confused which class to use `URI` or `URL` ?

Comment: Probably URI is preferable.  The URL API has some flaws.  For example, the URL.equals method attempts to resolve the hostname (!).